# How do I prevent xdmp:node-delete() from adding whitespace in my xml doc

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to `MOVE` a node from one xml document to another. Both documents are using the same namespace. I am trying to accomplish this by doing `xdmp:node-insert-child()` on the first document then `xdmp:node-delete()` on the second document in a sequence. The problem is that the `xdmp:node-delete()` is leaving spaces and returns in my xml doc. How can I keep this from happening?

Here is a code example...

```
let $documentId := 12345
let $newStatus := 123
let $processNode := $PROCESS-DOC//pex:process[(@documentId = $documentId)]    
let $newNode :=
       element { QName($TNS, 'process') } {
        attribute status { $newStatus },
        attribute documentId { $processNode/@documentId },
       }  
return
    if ($processNode and $newNode) then
      (xdmp:node-insert-child($PROCESS-COMPLETE-DOC/pex:processes, $newNode),xdmp:node-delete($processNode))
    else ()
```

Comment: Are you sure the whitespace wasn't there to begin with?

Comment: Each child node has a return after it but no space.  I am using the same xdmp:node-insert-child() to populate these nodes initially.

Comment: Oops, your right I just noticed that some of my nodes are being created with spaces after the node.  Looks like my problem is not deleting the nodes but rather why am I getting white space when creating them.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the whitespace is held in text nodes on either side of the node you are deleting. You could verify this by inspecting `xdmp:describe($processNode/preceding-sibling::text())` and `xdmp:describe($processNode/following-sibling::text())`. And if you like, you could `xdmp:node-delete` some or all of those text nodes too.

Comment: Running these will allow me to check for and delete any extra space before and after the node in my xml doc.  Thanks!